# How to optimize indexes on a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    vbShape, XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX,  GlobalID
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM features 
     WHERE vbShape IS NOT NULL) A
WHERE 
    XMIN <= -13036746.0212491 AND XMAX >= -13037147.3156476 AND 
    YMIN <= 3988531.90850796 AND YMAX >= 3988130.61410953
```

XMIN, XMAN, YMIN, YMAX are all float columns.

I need this query to run as fast as possible. Every millisecond is crucial. The `GlobalID` is the primary key.  What kind of indexes should I add for this table?  I currently have 4 non-clustered indexes defined on the table for the XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, and YMAX fields.  Should I also define a single index to include all the fields?  Or should I add two indexes?  One for the XMIN/XMAX and one for the YMIN/YMAX?  Is there any problem with adding too many indexes?

Comment: Is this some sort of spatial query? Have you looked at the geometry type and spatial indexes? I think you are checking  [`where geometry1.STContains(geometry2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: This is a spatial query but the geometery must be stored in binary format.  Therefore it will be slower to do STGeomFromWKB and then use STContains which is why we use min-max fields

Comment: But as you are finding out you can't index that efficiently. The best it can do is seek on one of the attributes and evaluate the rest as residual predicates. In the worst case and you are looking for values in the middle on all axes it will have to seek half the table

Comment: If you can modify the [vbShape] as a not nullable and put some default value instead of null and create an index on it then it will improve the performance. Except that you can check the performance by using temporary table to store data from subquery and then query the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

A single query can only use one of the indexes on each of the tables it reads from.  No matter how many indexes you create on the table, only one of them will get used by this query.

Therefore you want a single index that covers all the columns that are filtered in the query and includes the columns that are returned.

Comment: I have multiple indexes defined on this table for other purposes as well (some of the indexes aren't even on the fields that are in the query).  Will SQL Server know which index to use?

Comment: Yes, the optimizer should choose the best index for the query.  You can verify that it chooses the index you want by looking at the execution plan.   If for some reason it chooses a different index, you can force it to use the index you want with a `Query Hint`.